# How to use CSS to retrieve a text input by a user

Tags: css, background-color, shopify, liquid

I have my input tags with the text field, but was wondering how to take the input text a user entered and displayed it in the CSS

This may see very odd but It is for a color background option (#ffffff) that the designer will have access to input their own color and once they hit save, it will be added to the body background style.

I managed to have the css pick up an uploaded image through liquid, but I don't know how to retentive the input text for the color code. **I am using .Liquid through Shopify**

My CSS:

```
 body {  
  background:{% if settings.use_Site_background %}url('Site_background.jpg'){% endif %} no-repeat /////This is where I need the color code/////// fixed top right; 
}
```

My Settings:

```
 <tr>
  <td><label for="Background_color">Background color</label></td>
  <td><strong>#</strong><input name="Background_color" value="" id="Background_color" type="text" maxlength="6" /></td> 
</tr>
```

If there is an easier way to do this, I would really appreciate some help and it would be very appreciated!

Comment: If you've found an answer useful, request you to upvote/accept and you've found something tangential you can downvote as well. That not just helps those who answer questions, but also helps those asking questions - the fundamental & implicit rule of StackOverflow

Answer (score 1):

You'd get the value of the text field as follows:

```
var inputColor = document.getElementById('Background_color').value
```

and, then use it wherever you need to in your script

The complete script:

```
var btn = document.getElementById('pickColor');
btn.addEventListener('click', pickColorFunc, false);
function pickColorFunc(){
    var inputColor = document.getElementById('Background_color').value,
        myContainer = document.getElementById('content-box');
    myContainer.style.backgroundColor = inputColor;
}
```

The HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="Background_color" />
<button id="pickColor">Pick Color</button>
<div id="content-box">
</div>
```

And the little css I added by default to ensure the background color is seen:

```
#content-box{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
}
```

Please check this piece of code: http://jsfiddle.net/h5W6j/1

Comment: Aditya Saxena is right but one small mistake, its `.value`, not `.val()` other wise it will result in error.

Comment: Thanks @Shivam ..just edited that. I think I might have confused this with jQuery's method :)

Comment: lol...@Shivam I did wake up early though my time...for you probably it's late in the night :)

Comment: Thank you so much!

So I am assuming that I will need to put that code in the header somewhere so it loads when I open the page? and then add



in between 

   ///// no-repeat 'inputcolor' fixed top right;  /////

Sorry for the confusion, I am learning little by little.

Again, thank you so very much!

Comment: Okay cool...So what you need to do is add this to a script tag which is towards end of your html body. This ensures that there is an element by Background_color so that the script can run on it.


If however, the script came before the element in question, the script wouldn't find anything. In that case there will be an error in the statement.

Comment: Ok so when I take this code here:  document.write(inputColor)  <-and add it in the css, Nothing happens except for when I added the var inputColor = document.getElementById('Background_color').value code that you gave me, it shows now on my homepage as if it is not loaded or something?

Comment: ok nevermind I got the script tags working but still not background change.

Comment: Without confusing you/me more, here's the script you'd need : http://jsfiddle.net/h5W6j/

Comment: Ok so Now i understand I don't need to add anything to my css. but With the settings.html through Shopify, it is telling me that <button tags> are not allowed. is there an alternate? perhaps a checkbox? Thank you sooo much. I am sorry for confusing you lol

Comment: You can add click events on any element (div, span, anchor, input type="submit"). try any of those. Mine was just an example

Comment: so the script you gave to me works fine, but I realized that the settings.html does not support <script tags> I did add it to my theme but When someone goes into the settings.html file in the back end, the theme layout doesn't load because it is in the theme settings for the designer to customize. I think this is the reason I was trying to get the CSS originally to listen for the text input. Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: I found this code snippet with the theme documentation which works in the back end. is there a way to use this? <input name="text_color" class="color" type="text" value="#332211" /> Thanks

Comment: Instead of the use the name ="text_color" value as the id...so you'll do document.getElementById('text_color') instead. the default value of #332211 will be there in your text box

Comment: @Steven did the answer work for you? Let us know if you need more help.

Answer (score 0):

To Add to Aditya Saxena answer: **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sPpEp/3/)**

Place this in your footer:

```
document.getElementById('someForm').onsubmit = function() {
    var inputColor = document.getElementById('Background_color').value,
        $body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];

    $body.style.backgroundColor = inputColor;
    return false;
};
```

Comment: I got the script right but now I don't know how to add it to the line of CSS. what is the proper way to add the var into the line
? and Thank you for your input!

Comment: You don't have to add anything to the `css`, javascript will take care of that.